# hex and string in python

Tags: python, hex, ascii

here I want to replace # with \x 
but when I print h it doesn't give me the same result when I print y.decode()

does any one have an explaination and a solution for it ?

```
    s = "#53ule#69#6dan"
y = "\x53ule\x69\x6dan"
f = s.replace("#","\\x")
print f
h = f.decode()
print h
print y.decode()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\x` in `y` is not an actual backslash character followed by an `x` character, but rather the start of an [escape sequence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

The whole sequence `"\x53"` is `"S"` (because `"S"` is `0x53` in ASCII). Similarly, `"\x69"` is `"i"` and `"\x6d"` is `"m"`.

When you do your `replace` call to compute `f`, you don't get the escape sequence, but rather an actual backslash character followed by an `x` character.

I'm not sure there is a completely straight forward way to go from a hex string to a regular one, but this regex substitution will do the trick with some help from `int` and `chr`:

```
re.sub("#(..)", lambda match: chr(int(match.group(1), 16)), s)
```

Comment: @user3461464: `re.sub` does a regex substitution. It scans the input text (`s`) for the pattern (`"#(..)"`). The lambda function gets called for each match, and `match.group(1)` returns the two characters after the `#`. `int(some_str, 16)` decodes the hexidecimal characters to an integer, then `chr` turns the integer into an ASCII character. That return value gets put into the result as a replacement for the `#` and hex digits.

Comment: excuse me but why we use (1) in match.group(1) why don't we use (0) we only have one group, haven't we ??

Comment: @user3461464: I think the 1-based indexing of the groups is a historical artifact. Python's `re` module allows backreferences like `\1`, which traditionally refers to the first capturing group. I suspect the same indexing is simply carried over to the `group` method for consistency.

Comment: excuse me but what if I have an octal representation for that keyword, does this work well:

re.sub("\(..)", lambda match: chr(int(match.group(1), 10)), s)

someone suggested to transfer file to numeric representation and then search the keyword regarding to its numeric representation but I didn't find how to transfer the file to numeric. Do you haveany idea to do that ? thank you in advance for your help

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what structure your text with octal has, but you should be able to do something similar. Just use `8` as the second argument to `int` and you'll convert a string of octal to an integer.

Comment: sorry if I'm bothering you but if I want to use this with file is this correct:
import re...
fh = open("C:\\Users\\Suleiman JK\\Desktop\\test\\Hello.pdf","r+")..
stuff = fh.read()...
re.sub("#(..)", lambda match: chr(int(match.group(1), 16)), stuff)..
fh.close()...
fh = open("C:\\Users\\Suleiman JK\\Desktop\\test\\Hello.pdf")...
print fh.read()...

Comment: I tried what you said and replace 16 with 8 but it didn't work.....
import re......
 
stuff = "\123ul\145\151m\141\156"......
stuff = re.sub("\\([A-Fa-f0-9]{3})",lambda m:unichr(int(m.groups()[0],8)),stuff)......
print stuff......

Comment: @user3461464 Octal escapes in strings will be turned into characters with the corresponding ASCII code automatically, so you can't (and don't need to) match it with a regular expression. `"\123"` is already `"S"`, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.sub("#([A-Fa-f0-9]{2})",lambda m:unichr(int(m.groups()[0],16)),"#53ule#69#6dan")
```

might be what your looking for ...

Comment: As it looks like 2.x, could also use `h.decode('escape_string')` to interpret the escapes as though they were literals